# Is it correct I use just one connection always open instead a connection pooling?

Tags: node.js, oracle, connection-pooling

I have a node.js software that is all the time handling events and persisting something about them in Oracle database. It was developed before Oracle release your own driver, so i've used a community node module that haven't a pool connection yet. Then, i developed a Database module/class to interface the databank with DAOs.

So, I instantiate a database object (from Database class), that has ONE connection always open. Because of assinchronous requests, I can execute other queries when i wait for a callback.  I think my approach is like a pool limited to just one connection, but, is different to me share a connection in a assynchronous single-thread environment instead a synchronous multi-thread (in this case i see how it's bad)

This approach is bad? Should I change it for a connection pooling?

Comment: Unless there is a *need* a long-running connection (e.g. for a long running transaction, which is questionable for other means) there really isn't a reason *not* to use pooling.

Comment: depends on what you mean by *"correct"*. It will work, but as your traffic grows you may run into problems.